# Assigning a variable (with wildcard) with parentheses versus none

Tags: bash, variables, parentheses

I have a simple naive question, I've figured out how to make my script run but I'd like to know why it didn't work previously.

I was assigning a variable with a wildcard using syntax similar to:

`var=$dir/$subj/name*text*text.nii.gz`

I could call the proper filename with ls $file, but when I tried to substitute in $file as an input into a command line (using FSL for image processing), I got an error saying it couldn't find the file with wildcards in place.

However, when I assign the variable with parentheses:

`var=($dir/$subj/name*text*text.nii.gz)`

It runs just fine. I'm assuming there are other and probably better ways to do this, but I'm just wondering why the initial variable assignment didn't work, and what the optimal way to assign variables in this manner is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider a directory with three files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

Now define a variable:

```
$ var=file*
```

We can see what is in `var` by using `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="file*"
```

As you can see, `var` still has the `*` in it.  This is because *pathname expansion* is not performed for variable assignments.  Consequently, `var` will not always work as you may have wanted.  For example:

```
$ ls "$var"
ls: cannot access file*: No such file or directory
```

Next, let's try creating an array:

```
$ var=(file*)
$ declare -p var
declare -a var='([0]="file1" [1]="file2" [2]="file3")'
```

As you can see, *pathname expansion* is performed on arrays.  Consequently, the following does work:

```
$ ls "$var"
file1
```

But, note that, for an array, `$var` refers only to the first element.  If you wanted to access all its entries, a more complex notation is needed:

```
$ ls "${var[@]}"
file1  file2  file3
```